# ArangoDB running multiple queries

Tags: arangodb

I want to run more than one query .. how to do it?

eg, I have below two queries -

```
FOR doc IN users
    RETURN doc

FOR doc IN users
    RETURN { user: doc, newAttribute: true }
```

If I have to run both queries I have to run them separately, is there a way to execute a script or I need to put a semicolon at the end like SQL and run it.

Can I use arangosh?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `LET` to execute multiple sub-queries in a single queries:

```
LET firstUserResult = (
   FOR doc IN users
   RETURN doc 
)

LET secondUserResult = (
   FOR doc IN users
   RETURN { user: doc, newAttribute: true }
)

RETURN { first: firstUserResult, second: secondUserResult }
```

Some notes here - you will need to add an additional `RETURN` statement at the end of the query. This will definitely work for reads but you may run into issues when trying to write in multiple queries.

Comment: How can I combine them in javascript drivers ?
For me, the number of queries get dynamic:

I have a list of objs which needs to be stored in db. I need to check if any obj in the same collect exists with the same id, then delete the existing and insert the new.

query1 = delete if the document with same id exists
query2 = insert the new document

both the queries I need to run for each items of the list that I have received from the user.